Render　デプロイがうまくいかない
Rubyにて個人アプリ開発をしています。
Renderにてデプロイを試みたのですが，同じ箇所で何度もループしてしまい，502エラーが出てしまいます。
ですが，Renderダッシュボード上では，Liveと緑色のチェックマークが出ています。
解決策をご存じの方，何卒教えていただきたいです。
Renderでのログ
Installing foreman...
Successfully installed foreman-0.88.1
1 gem installed
16:53:44 web.1  | started with pid 19
16:53:44 js.1   | started with pid 20
16:53:44 css.1  | started with pid 23
16:53:47 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.19
16:53:48 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.19
16:53:48 css.1  | $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify
16:53:49 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets
16:53:51 js.1   | 
16:53:51 js.1   |   app/assets/builds/application.js      324.2kb
16:53:51 js.1   |   app/assets/builds/application.js.map  596.9kb
16:53:51 js.1   | 
16:53:51 js.1   | Done in 3.50s.
16:53:52 js.1   | exited with code 0
16:53:52 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
16:53:52 web.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
16:53:52 css.1  | exited with code 1

ログ内でのエラー文
==> Port scan timeout reached, no open ports detected. Bind your service to at least one port. If you don't need to receive traffic on any port, create a background worker instead.
==> Docs on specifying a port: https://render.com/docs/web-services#port-binding

ブログ記事等を読み以下追記
config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.version = "1.0"

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  custom/bubble.js
  custom/default_values.js
  custom/preview.js
  custom/search.js
  custom/top_bubble.js
  custom/tourguide.js
)

RenderのHPに記載されていたデプロイ方法に変更
bin/render-build.shの作成
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

bundle install
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
bundle exec rails assets:clean

参考にさせていただいた記事
https://qiita.com/MIDO-ruby7/items/9718b40c97e4d282ae83
https://docs.render.com/deploy-rails
